# When to use MPI_BUFFER_ATTACH?

Tags: mpi

As far as I know, MPI_BUFFER_ATTACH must be called by a process if it is going to do buffered communication. But does this include the standard MPI_SEND as well? We know that MPI_SEND may behave either as a synchronous send or as a buffered send.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `MPI_Buffer_attach()` only if you plan to perform (explicitly) buffered sends via `MPI_Bsend()`.

If you only plan to `MPI_Send()` or `MPI_Isend()`, then you do not need to invoke `MPI_Buffer_attach()`.

FWIW, buffered sends are error prone and I strongly encourage you not to use them.

Answer (score -3):

**MPI_Buffer_attach**

Attaches a user-provided buffer for sending

**Synopsis**

int MPI_Buffer_attach(void *buffer, int size)

Input Parameters

**buffer**
initial buffer address (choice)

**size**
buffer size, in bytes (integer)

> **Notes**
>
> The size given should be the sum of the sizes of all outstanding
>   Bsends that you intend to have, plus MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD for each Bsend
>   that you do. For the purposes of calculating size, you should use
>   MPI_Pack_size. In other words, in the code

```
 MPI_Buffer_attach( buffer, size );
 MPI_Bsend( ..., count=20, datatype=type1,  ... );
 ...
 MPI_Bsend( ..., count=40, datatype=type2, ... );
```

the value of size in the MPI_Buffer_attach call should be greater than the value computed by

```
 MPI_Pack_size( 20, type1, comm, &s1 );
 MPI_Pack_size( 40, type2, comm, &s2 );
 size = s1 + s2 + 2 * MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD;
```

The MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD gives the maximum amount of space that may be used in the buffer for use by the BSEND routines in using the buffer. This value is in mpi.h (for C) and mpif.h (for Fortran).
Thread and Interrupt Safety
The user is responsible for ensuring that multiple threads do not try to update the same MPI object from different threads. This routine should not be used from within a signal handler.

The MPI standard defined a thread-safe interface but this does not mean that all routines may be called without any thread locks. For example, two threads must not attempt to change the contents of the same MPI_Info object concurrently. The user is responsible in this case for using some mechanism, such as thread locks, to ensure that only one thread at a time makes use of this routine. Because the buffer for buffered sends (e.g., MPI_Bsend) is shared by all threads in a process, the user is responsible for ensuring that only one thread at a time calls this routine or MPI_Buffer_detach.

**Notes for Fortran**

All MPI routines in Fortran (except for MPI_WTIME and MPI_WTICK) have an additional argument ierr at the end of the argument list. ierr is an integer and has the same meaning as the return value of the routine in C. In Fortran, MPI routines are subroutines, and are invoked with the call statement.
All MPI objects (e.g., MPI_Datatype, MPI_Comm) are of type INTEGER in Fortran.

**Errors**

All MPI routines (except MPI_Wtime and MPI_Wtick) return an error value; C routines as the value of the function and Fortran routines in the last argument. Before the value is returned, the current MPI error handler is called. By default, this error handler aborts the MPI job. The error handler may be changed with MPI_Comm_set_errhandler (for communicators), MPI_File_set_errhandler (for files), and MPI_Win_set_errhandler (for RMA windows). The MPI-1 routine MPI_Errhandler_set may be used but its use is deprecated. The predefined error handler MPI_ERRORS_RETURN may be used to cause error values to be returned. Note that MPI does not guarentee that an MPI program can continue past an error; however, MPI implementations will attempt to continue whenever possible.

**MPI_SUCCESS**

No error; MPI routine completed successfully.

**MPI_ERR_BUFFER**

Invalid buffer pointer. Usually a null buffer where one is not valid.

**MPI_ERR_INTERN**

An internal error has been detected. This is fatal. Please send a bug report to mpi-bugs@mcs.anl.gov.

See Also MPI_Buffer_detach, MPI_Bsend

**Refer Here For More**

[Buffer allocation and usage](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node42.htm)

[Programming with MPI](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/MPI/paper_04.pdf)

[MPI - Bsend usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606441/mpi-bsend-usage)